# Zend Framework not deleting table entry

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to delete a post from my table but the code is deleting all table data and not just the one post.

delete.php

```
<?php
class Form_Delete extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        @parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setName('Delete');
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('Title');
        $description = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('Description');
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Delete');
        $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');
        $cancel = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('cancel');
        $cancel->setAttrib('id', 'cancelbutton');
        $this->addElements( array( $id, $title, $description, $submit, $cancel ));
    }
}
```

and my controller code

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
        //action body
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $postid = (int)$request->getParam('id');
        $post = new Model_DbTable_Posts();
        $result = $post->getPost($postid);
        $this->view->post = $result;
        if(!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
            $this->_redirect('posts/view/id/'.$postid);
        }

        $identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();

        $acl = new Model_Acl();
        if( $acl->isAllowed( $identity['Role'] ,'posts','edit','delete') ) {
            $deleteForm = new Form_Delete();
            $deleteModel = new Model_DbTable_Posts();
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                if ($deleteForm->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                    $deleteModel->delete($dpostid);                 
                    $this->_redirect('index/index');
                }
            }
            $this->view->deleteForm = $deleteForm;
        }
```

I have tried for hours to get this working but can ether get it to delete all or nothing. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `delete()` the where clause to evaluate. Try:

```
$where = $deleteModel->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $dpostid);
$deleteModel->delete($where);
```

Change 'id' to whatever your primary key is.

Also `@parent::__construct($options);` in your form class is a little odd. Change that to `parent::__construct();`. No need to supress the error if you don't generate one.

Comment: Even if the answer is quite old I hope for some help.
`$_t  = new self();
        $where = $_t->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->quoteInto('item_cat_id = ?', $itemId);
        echo $where;
        $_t->getDbTable()->delete($where);`

The where clause is correct (from the echo) but the rows (3) are never deleted. I'm executing this code from an static method in a Model that extends TG_Model_Abstract. Any hints?